# How to get out of a binding situation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, callback

I have the following code that I am trying to use to register a callback on an array of buttons.  But I cannot seem to understand how I can bind the strings that I would need in the callback.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.car_types.length; ++i) {

    this.select_car_buttons.push($("#button_select_car_" +
                this.car_types[i].car_type));

    this.select_car_buttons[this.select_car_buttons.length - 1]
        .click(function() {
            console.log(this.car_types[i].car_type);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Somehow the `this` object is the button itself and not the object under whose scope the function is called.

**EDIT** : It seems like the this object was indeed being passed in properly.  The issue is that the variable `i` is not going out of scope and is being captured by reference not by value.  How should I go about solving this problem?

Also there seem to lots of such issues with JavaScript as a language (at least things that can be classified as an issue considering the semantics employed by the traditional C family languages such as C and C++ to be correct),  is there some article I can read that warns me against these types of issues?

**ANOTHER EDIT** : On trying making a closure with the value of `i` captured by value I tried the following code

```
this.select_car_buttons[this.select_car_buttons.length - 1]
   .click((function(scoped_i) {
      return function() {
            console.log(this.car_types[scoped_i].car_type);
      }.bind(this);                               
}(i)));
```

But I get the following error in Safari

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scoped_i')
```

**EDIT** : The same code works in Firefox and Chrome but not in Safari!

Comment: Why don't you just avoid this kind of tricky things with `this` and on the scope object, add `self = this;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @Curious sorry deleted my answer. I'd end up repeating what's written in the link above

Comment: @LimH. I still have not been able to solve my problem... `let` gives a syntax error on safari..

Comment: @MiguelLattuada How do I achieve what you are suggesting?

Comment: self = this; before the for loop, and every time you want to access to your object use self.something, and when you want to access the scope, use this.

Comment: @MiguelLattuada How would that help?  `self` is just a reference to `this` which is just a reference to the bound object right?

Comment: Yes, but the difference is, `self` will not be attached to the current scope that it's called.

Comment: @MiguelLattuada I still don't understand the benefit.  Could you please elaborate?  I come from a traditional C/C++/Python background so I don't know much about what javascript

Comment: Here it's a great article by Todd, https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/, it has a great technical approach, and cover a few more topics. I hope this will help more than my random comments. `What is the this keyword and how does Scope affect it?`

Comment: I still cannot find a good solution to my problem

Comment: Since you're dealing with an array, just use the car_types.forEach method to encapsulate the scope, even down the road when onclick is fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scope issue. For modern browsers (*that support ES6*) you could just change `var` to `let` in your `for` loop and it would get fixed.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < this.car_types.length; ++i)
```

---

Quoting the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

> The **let** statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

---

For more global support (*non ES6 support*) use an immediately invoked function to create extra scope for the variable (*which you will pass as a parameter*)

```js
this.select_car_buttons[this.select_car_buttons.length - 1]
  .click((function(scoped_i) { // IIF starts here, the new variable is called scoped_i for verbosity
    return function() { // your original function code goes here
      console.log(this.car_types[scoped_i].car_type); // use the newly scoped variable
    }.bind(this);
  }.bind(this)(i))); // end and execute the IIF while passing the i variable to it
```

Comment: What is `let`?  I could look this up but you answering is probably going to be faster in context

Comment: What scope does `var` have?

Comment: `var` is function block scoped

Comment: Does `let`, trick `this`to not change its value depending on the scope?

Comment: Using `let` is giving me an error in safari for some reason

Comment: @curious yes, it seems safari is behind on support. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=let For global coverage you'd be better off using the extra function closure.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Could you suggest a solution that works at least on Safari, Chrome and Firefox?  I have never written code in JavaScript and this is seriously hindering my productivity haha.  You know much more than I do probably and I would love to hear your advice about this

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli How do I use the extra function closure?

Comment: I get the following error on using your code `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scoped_i')`

Comment: I still cannot find a decent solution to this problem

Comment: did you include the `(i)` part at the end ? (*could you post your code as it currently is*)

Comment: @Curious can you run https://jsfiddle.net/5tueghqp/ and see the console if it prints correctly ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli YES! It works!  Could you explain how the `scoped_i` is a copy of the `i` please?  I will mark your answer as accepted now!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this structure do make a lot of closures and make code very hard to read. Since you use jQuery, there are a much better way to solve this problem which saves the data in html:

html:

```
<button class="select-car" data-car-type="CarA">Select CarA</button>
<button class="select-car" data-car-type="CarB">Select CarB</button>
<!-- And a lot of buttons -->
```

js:

```
var selectCarOnClick = function() {
  console.info($(this).data('car-type'));
};
$('button.select-car').click(selectCarOnClick);
```

Live exmaple: http://codepen.io/SCLeo/pen/VaQYjW

If you have a lot of other information to store and you want to use a object to store them instead of DOM, you can save car-name or car-id instead of car-type.

Here is the document about $.data: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/